# Need help iterating over a dataframe to get just the date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I have a pandas dataframe, date_win, created from a sqlite3 query. It looks like this:

```
             0
0   2011-01-29
1   2011-03-19
2   2011-05-07
3   2011-02-19
4   2011-03-12
5   2011-01-22
6   2011-04-17
```

I would like to iterate over it to get the date out, convert to unix and put it into the Dark Sky api.  When I get the date out and assigned to a variable and put into my datetime conversion, the error is:

> ValueError: time data '0    2011-01-29\nName: 0, dtype: object' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

I have tried using this for loop:
`for i in range(0,len(date_win)):`

And:
`for i in date_win:`

Here is my full code snippet:

```py
for i in range(0,len(date_win)):

    s = str(date_win.iloc[i])


    dt = round(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d").timetuple()))
    dt = str(dt)
    resp = requests.get('https://api.darksky.net/forecast/[my_key]/52.52,13.4050,' + dt)
    data=resp.json()
    print(data['currently']['summary'])
```

Here is the error code:

> ValueError: time data '0    2011-01-29\nName: 0, dtype: object' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

The api call works if I use `s = "2011-01-01"` or hard code into the api request.  I'm just not doing the iteration correctly.

Comment: please format your code properly and format the sample data properly

Answer (score 0):

You can output a column of formatted date strings to a list using [strftime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html)

e.g.

```
d = ['2009-08-19',
    '2005-06-04',
    '2003-04-05']
​
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['dates'])
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])  

         dates
0   2009-08-19
1   2005-06-04
2   2003-04-05

dates = df['dates'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').values
```

By using `.values` on the series, `dates` will be a plain python list of formatted strings, you can then loop over this normally and apply them to your API.

If you wanted to keep the strings in the dataframe you can just assign another column

```
df['formatted'] = df['dates'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Worth noting that you can use [itertuples](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) or similar to loop over a dataframe.

Comment: Elembie, thank you for the quick response.  I tried out your code suggestion and used the  "for" loop - no error this time, but all the dates came out as "NaT".

Comment: I think your dates might not be stored as `datetime` objects in your dataframe. Have you added in the `pd.to_datetime` function as in the second line of my code? Make sure you're saving the output to the column you then want to export. To check the data type of your dataframe columns you can `print(df.dtypes)`. They should be something like `datetime64[ns]`.

Comment: Yup.  I did that.  I am working with sqlite3, could that be part of the issue (are datetime objects supported?) ?  I've asked an instructor to look at my code and help me out on this issue and another one I was having.  If I figure it out, I'll post my update.  Many thanks.

Comment: sqlite definitely supports `datetime` - regardless, you already have the data in a pandas object so you should be able to convert to whatever pandas supported object type you want. Just double check all your column references, and print out the dataframe and `df.dtypes` at all stages to check you're not missing anything. Let me know if you figure it out!